# C#, can`t find TreeView child node by text

Tags: c#, treeview, find

i have the following code to find a child node in TreeView:

```
public void NodeHinzufuegen()
{
    // Other stuff above
    ReturnCompleteFolderPath(erstellterPunkt.Text);
    // Other stuff below
}



public void ReturnCompleteFolderPath(string nodename)
{
    TreeNode[] tempnode = tree_vorlagen.Nodes.Find(nodename, true);
        if (tempnode.Length > 0)
        {
            //tree_vorlagen.SelectedNode = tempnode[0];
            MessageBox.Show(tempnode[0].Parent.Name);
        }
}
```

---

So ReturnCompleteFolderPath() is called and succesfully transmits the text to ReturnCompleteFolderPath (checked by mouseover in debug). If I mouseover tempnode in debug mode it says {System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode[0]} and if i mouseover tempnode.Length it says "0". So it seems the node couldn`t be found. Any ideas about this?

My Treeview looks like this.

Test1

- Test2

"Test2" is the text transmitted to ReturnCompleteFolderPath  function.

Comment: you have to create a key when you add a node to then use it in the find method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [TreeNodeCollection.Find documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection.find%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Finds the tree nodes with specified key, optionally searching subnodes.
>
> ...
>
> The Name property corresponds to the key for a TreeNode in the TreeNodeCollection.

Unless you're setting up a Name for your TreeNodes, this method will never find results. If you want to search by text, you could attach the names when the nodes are created

```
    TreeNode test2 = new TreeNode("Test2") { Name = "Test2" };
```

or even add names to all of them:

```
    // Fetch each node without a name and give it one
    foreach (TreeNode node in tree_vorlagen.Nodes.Find("", true))
        node.Name = node.Text;

    // Now the "Test2" node can be found
    Console.WriteLine(tree_vorlagen.Nodes.Find("Test2", true).Length); // Prints 1
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Added the name after creation and transfered the name instead of the text. Works great :)

Answer (score 0):

The `TreeNodeCollection.Find` method finds nodes where the *Name* property matches the search string, i.e. not the *Text*. So I'd guess that's why it's not returning anything (seeing how I didn't know that myself until just now either)!

So either make sure you set the name too, or whip up your own search function to find it.

[More information here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection.find%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)